# Spritekit - could not create physics body - image occasionally returns nil

Tags: sprite-kit

I have looked at these questions but their answers did not work for me: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608790/could-not-create-physics-body-swift), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579932/spritekit-physicsbody-could-not-create-physics-body). I am targeting iOS 10.0. Occasionally when running the code a physicsBody is not created due to a problem with the texture/image and occasionally it does get created but is completely wrong yet I can't find anything wrong with the image, no stray pixels. Sometimes it does get created perfectly fine, about 1/3 times. Setting the alpha threshold as one answer suggests also doesn't change anything.

[image: The image]

Code:

```swift
let pigeon: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pigeonHitBox")

    init(){
        pigeon.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        pigeon.position = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 631)
        pigeon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: pigeon.texture ?? SKTexture(imageNamed: "pigeonHitBox"), size: pigeon.size)
        pigeon.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    }
```

Example of completely wrong outline

[image: image2]

Comment: Explain why you pass `pigeon.texture ?? SKTexture(imageNamed: "pigeonHitBox")`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I pass that because simply passing pigeon.texture results in an error as the SKTexture is an optional, using `SKTexture(imageNamed: "pigeonHitBox")` or `pigeon.texture!` result in the same thing, providing a default value was just the last thing I tried code-wise

Comment: Well I don't understand why it would fail.  Perhaps that is important and the texture needs a frame to load before it can be used by the physics system.  I know that in my game engine, when I create a texture I create it using storage mode `MTLStorageModePrivate` which means only the GPU can access it, but also means the loaded texture must be blitted into it, which requires a loop through the renderer.  See if you can improve things by trying that.

Comment: One thing I've run into is trying to use some SKTexture info (the textureRect) shortly after creating the texture and finding that the results occasionally didn't make sense. Eventually I came to the conclusion that some part of the texture creation was happening lazily. Adding an explicit reference to texture.size() seemed to force it to do whatever it needed to do, and then textureRect was always OK. Try passing pigeon.texture!.size() as the size in the SKPhysicsBody init.

Comment: @bg2b I tried this out and while it was a good idea it did not work for me, I'm not certain but I think it's a problem with either 13.0 or my 13.0 simulator, I tried other textures all of which failed and decided to test on a 12.2 simulator and as far as I can tell it works fine (after about 30 runs) no weird outlines or null textures, hope this is fixed in 13.1 which I can't download due to internet right now

Comment: Physics bodies from textures in iOS 13 is currently broken (at least as of 13.1.2). See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062098/ios-13-sprite-kit-issues  It does work in the simulator for me, but not on a real device. I and at least one other person have reported the issue and code to reproduce it to Apple, but no response yet. For now I'm creating an SKPhysicsBody from a CGPath for the convex hull of the texture's alpha channel.